# Django view doen't able to return json on ajax success?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, jsonresponse

I have tried both JsonResponse and HttpResponse(along with json.dumps) but even though ajax is returning to success, returned json can't be parsed by $.parseJSON(returned_json).

I am sure that the problem is not with parsing($.parseJSON(returned_json)) by printing out json.dumps value in terminal and copying the value into a variable and giving it to $.parseJSON, and it successfully parsed it.

I tried to pass simplest json but it also fails whose example I am showing below:
In views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

In my view which is handling ajax:

```
return JsonResponse({"stat":"Success"})
```

In my ajax file:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"feed/get_comments/",
    type: "GET",
    data:{c_id: cid}, //cid is a variable initialized above and not creating any problem
    success: function(ret_json){
        alert("Inside success"); //Running everytime
        var sam_json = '{"stat":"Success"}'; //same as what is given in JsonResponse
        var data = $.parseJSON(ret_json); //for debugging change to sam_json
        alert(data); //with sam_json alerting with dictionary, with ret_json not giving any alert
    },
```

Instead of JsonResponse if I use json.dumps along with HttpResponse same thing is happening.
From above I can only conclude that JsonResponse and HttpResponse is not returning data in json format even though json.dumps is successfully converting in json format(as I copied this and pasted in ajax variable). Please help.

Comment: I have tried that also but it was of no use. dataType:"json" defines the returned type and if we are parsing it explicitly(using $.parseJSON()), we can skip it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseJSON` isn't needed.

Since you're just working with a dictionary you can just access it as you would with any other dictionary in javascript

For example.

```
alert(ret_json.stat);
```

Answer (score 1):

With HttpResponse and json dump, you can get response data in js like this

```
var val = $.ajax({
    url:"feed/get_comments/",
    type: "GET",
    data:{c_id: cid}, //cid is a variable initialized above and not creating any problem
    success: function(ret_json){
        alert("Inside success"); //Running everytime
        var sam_json = '{"stat":"Success"}'; //same as what is given in JsonResponse
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(val.responseText); //for debugging change to sam_json
        alert(data); //with sam_json alerting with dictionary, with ret_json not giving any alert
     },
```

`val.responseText` will have the data you are sending from view.